# Group values based on criterias -R

Tags: r, data.table, group

i have this kind of dataset:

```
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 q1= c(1, 2, 3, 5), 
                 q2= c(3, 5, 2, 4), 
                 q3= c(2, 3, 4, 3),
                 education = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
```

I want toget a table that counts the values into different groups:
All ID with value 1,3,4 should be counted in a group called "YES"
All ID with value 1,3 should be counted in a group called "maybe" (some ID will be counted twice here)
All ID with value 5,2 should be under "NO"

final output should be a table for each education level and based on the q's:

```
   YES    maybe    NO
q1
q2
q3
```

Hope you can help me

Comment: Yes! correct! I can see it is corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a `data.table`-native approach:

```r
library(data.table)
categs <- list(YES=c(1,3,4), maybe=c(1,3), NO=c(2,5))
out <- melt(dt, "education", measure.vars = c("q1", "q2", "q3")
  )[, names(categs) := lapply(categs, `%in%`, x = value)
  ][, lapply(.SD, function(z) as.numeric(sum(z))), by = .(education, variable), .SDcols = names(categs)
  ][, names(categs) := lapply(.SD, function(z) z/sum(z)),
    by = .(education), .SDcols = names(categs)]
out
#     education variable   YES maybe    NO
#        <char>   <fctr> <num> <num> <num>
#  1:         A       q1   0.5   0.5   0.0
#  2:         B       q1   0.0   0.0   0.5
#  3:         C       q1   0.5   1.0   0.0
#  4:         D       q1   0.0   0.0   1.0
#  5:         A       q2   0.5   0.5   0.0
#  6:         B       q2   0.0   0.0   0.5
#  7:         C       q2   0.0   0.0   1.0
#  8:         D       q2   0.5   0.0   0.0
#  9:         A       q3   0.0   0.0   1.0
# 10:         B       q3   1.0   1.0   0.0
# 11:         C       q3   0.5   0.0   0.0
# 12:         D       q3   0.5   1.0   0.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there a way to make the sum be in percent? I have larger numbers than this and want it to in percentage?

Comment: If my total number og IDs is 5000 how can i get the percentages for each group instead of the sum

Comment: You just need to divide a value by the sum of the value, per group. See my edit.

Comment: And i can times with 100 in this line z/sum(z)) ?

Comment: or even 101 if you'd prefer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, whether I understood what exactly you wish for. But as far as I understood it this will give you what you want:

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt <- data.table(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
                 q1= c(1, 2, 3, 5), 
                 q2= c(3, 5, 2, 4), 
                 q3= c(2, 3, 4, 3),
                 education = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))

dt <- dt %>% pivot_longer(q1:q3) %>% 
  group_by(education, name) %>% 
  mutate(YES = sum(value %in% c(1,3, 4)),
         maybe = sum(value %in% c(1, 3)),
         NO = sum(value %in% c(2, 5))) %>%
  dplyr::select(!c(value, ID)) %>%
  distinct()

dt
```

Output:

```
   education name    YES maybe    NO
   <chr>     <chr> <int> <int> <int>
 1 A         q1        1     1     0
 2 A         q2        1     1     0
 3 A         q3        0     0     1
 4 B         q1        0     0     1
 5 B         q2        0     0     1
 6 B         q3        1     1     0
 7 C         q1        1     1     0
 8 C         q2        0     0     1
 9 C         q3        1     0     0
10 D         q1        0     0     1
11 D         q2        1     0     0
12 D         q3        1     1     0
```

So for each education level and each q it gives you a count of YES, maybe and NO.

**EDIT: ----**

In case you want a separate table for each education level, use this code:

```
for (level in unique(dt$education)) {
  assign(level, dt %>% filter(education == level), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Now you have a table for each education level like this:

```
A
  education name    YES maybe    NO
  <chr>     <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 A         q1        1     1     0
2 A         q2        1     1     0
3 A         q3        0     0     1
```

Comment: what if the q names is in reality: s_28, s_29,_s_35, s_34 does that make a difference doing the pivot_longer ?

Comment: Also how did you make 'name'

Comment: And value is not existing

Comment: Value and name result from the pivot_longer-command. In case you have other column names you can just replace the column names in the pivot_longer-command and you are good to go :)